# Skipping Items During Data Binding in gridview c#

Tags: c#

how to skip specific item in row bind event C#

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you meant, Why do you have to skip the item? Is the data coming from the DB? If so, just don't include the item from your select query.

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark it as accepted. Then go back through your questions and do the same. 20 questions and only 4 accepted is not pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

You could

1. Filter the data via the SQL query.
2. Filter the data via a table select if binding to a datatable/dataset
3. Filter data via a DataView
4. Use the RowDataBound event

Edit ~ Here is how to use the RowDataBound

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;

    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        //A value to check for
        string myValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "myColumn").ToString();

        if ((myValue == "a")) {
            //Hide the row
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how this will affect your paging....if you do have one.

Comment: can you plz explain more how Use the RowDatBound event ...?

Comment: i used this and it resolved my problem  dtUserDevices.DefaultView.RowFilter = "UserDeviceId <> '" + aUserDeviceID + "'";